# didUpdatePushCredentials not called anymore [Xcode 8.3.3]

Tags: ios, xcode, pushkit

I've just update Xcode to version 8.3.3 and `pushRegistry:didUpdatePushCredentials:forType:` is not being called anymore.

Did something related to PushKit changed in this new version of Xcode?

This is my code for registering:

```
    _voipRegistry = [[PKPushRegistry alloc] initWithQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    _voipRegistry.delegate = self;
    _voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:PKPushTypeVoIP];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no change to Xcode version 8.3.3 with pushkit. There is syntax level change with swift language from 2.2 to 3.X, but nothing changed with Objective C. ( I see your code is in Objective C )

I suggest once you can cross verify your code.

---

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <PushKit/PushKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,PKPushRegistryDelegate>
{
    PKPushRegistry *pushRegistry;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

---

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    pushRegistry = [[PKPushRegistry alloc] initWithQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    pushRegistry.delegate = self;
    pushRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:PKPushTypeVoIP];

    return YES;
}

#define PushKit Delegate Methods

- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials:(PKPushCredentials *)credentials forType:(NSString *)type{
    if([credentials.token length] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"voip token NULL");
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"PushCredentials: %@", credentials.token);
}

- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload");
}
```

[Refer](https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It seems that restarting my mac solved the issue :/
Anyway, thanks for the help.